# Update nested object within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of "activities" stored as `$scope.activities`. I'm iterating over these in an ng-repeat, accessing nested values and objects along the way.

Some of these nested objects have actions associated with them, such as "liking" and "rsvp'ing", when then makes a call to my backend and should update the value within the ng-repeat. That logic looks like this:

```
$scope.rsvpToEvent = function(eventId) {
            eventService.rsvp(eventId, $rootScope.user._id).then(function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.activities.length; i++) {
                    if($scope.activities[i].event) {
                        if($scope.activities[i].event._id == data._id) {
                            $scope.activities[i].event = data;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            function (errorMessage) {
            });
        };
```

I've also tried passing `$index` to the function and accessing that activity directly, rather than having the for loop.

This executes successfully and updates the value if I console.log it, but it's not updating the dom or the values of the ng-repeat. I'm using similar logic on another page and it's working fine, so I'm assuming it's due to the fact that I'm trying to update a nested object like this (the other page's logic isn't on nested objects).

Other similar questions have said it's a problem with the scope not getting updated. However, if I wrap this in `$scope.$apply()` or call it afterwards, I get the "digest already in progress" error. If I try to do a "safe" scope apply by checking the phase, it just doesn't get called at all since a digest is already in progress. Is there another approach to this to ensure that the dom/ng-repeat will get updated?

Comment: Can you post your code in Fiddle/Plunker? take template : http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/637/

Comment: Just FYI angular has a helper to loop all items in an array or a dictionary, called "angular.forEach". It really makes life simpler when looping stuff :)

Comment: Could this be an inheritance issue? If you where to overwrite the activities object in say a directive or another child-scope of rsvpToEvent then any changes you do here won't apply anymore. You would have to overwrite the entire object for that to happen, so it does not feel all that likely.

Comment: @MaximShoustin I attempted to make a dumbed-down version on jsfiddle, seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/638/, but it actually works there. The objects I'm working with in the real environment are much more complex with lots of nested values (they're from a mongoDB query), so that might be the problem? Either that or the fact that my real-world example is within a service call

Comment: @ErikHonn that's actually great to know, I hated having these ugly for loops everywhere. Thanks!

As for the inheritance issue, I'm not 100% sure I understand you. These values/objects are not being changed in any directives or outside controllers

Comment: its easy to simulate service async call.

Comment: There are several questions with people who overwrite objects in child-scopes and then have trouble changing them in the controller (note that ng-repeat and ng-include use child scopes). If you never assign that object anywhere else then your problem probably has nothing to do with inheritance, just wanted to check that it wasn't the case since it's a common problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pass the whole activity into the function if it's easier.

```
<div ng-repeat="activity in activities" ng-click="rsvpToEvent(activity)">
```

Then you don't need the loop or anything like that.

```
$scope.rsvpToEvent = function(activity) {
        eventService.rsvp(activity.event._id, $rootScope.user._id).then(function (data) {
           activity.event = data;
        },
        function (errorMessage) {
        });
    };
```

Comment: Wow, I could've swore I had already tried that... It seems so obvious now! That worked perfectly, thank you.